# node js FS accessSync set global variable path fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, fs

I have a problem with Sync function in FS core of nodejs. 
for example I have a nodejs file with this syntax

```
var y;
fs.accessSync("real_exixs_path", fs.R_OK | fs.W_OK, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("File error!");
  } else {
    y = "foo";
  }
});
```

after running this code the global "y" variable still remain `undefined` and it won't set to "foo". Can someone help me?

Comment: @thefourtheye this question isn't duplicate...
I've found a solution... the Sync function don't have callback argument ! 
Synchronous version of fs.access(). This throws if any accessibility checks fail, and does nothing otherwise.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @thefourtheye my question ask about the synchronization function (Sync function) not about Asynchronous. 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the nodejs FS documentation:

> fs.accessSync(path[, mode])#
>
> Synchronous version of fs.access(). This throws if any accessibility checks fail, and does nothing otherwise.

the accessSync function don't have callback argument so you need to throws

here an example:

```
try{
   fs.accessSync("real_exixs_path", fs.R_OK | fs.W_OK)
}catch(e){
   //error
}
//success!
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer has an error, it will always run "success" whether a file exists or not.

Corrected version:

```
try{
   require('fs').accessSync("filename.ext", fs.R_OK | fs.W_OK)
   //code to action if file exists

}catch(e){
   //code to action if file does not exist
}
```

or, wrap it in a function:

```
function fileExists(filename){
  try{
    require('fs').accessSync(filename)
    return true;
  }catch(e){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is that? Because you used `require('fs')`, or something else?

Comment: Is your question regarding what is the error in the Accepted Answer? If so, the error is: the "//Success!" code is in the wrong place - it will *always* be run, whether the file exists or not.  The correct behavior is "//Success!" should only be executed if the file actually exists... See my sample code above for an example.

Comment: Yes, of course. Stupid me. It seemed so obvious that I didn't even think of it, so I thought you meant something else (like `fs.accessSync("real_exixs_path", fs.R_OK | fs.W_OK)` always resulting in an error for some weird reason).

Comment: @MtlDev thanks for this! The first example fails though as you reference the `fs` constants without setting the `fs` variable. In this instance you can probably just remove them.